# Unity 2D rotation not smooth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

Does not rotate **"fluid, smooth"** in the left angle. The left angle turns but is not fluid and smooth. **No angles between angles**.

No problem in the right part. The problem is on the left side. The turns on the right side are smooth. Turning angles on the left side are not **fluid, smooth**.

**Watch the problem:** https://youtu.be/kuBWoF5r2Bs

**Gun Sprite C# Code:**

```
 public GameObject projectile;

    public Camera cam;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //rotation
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 objectPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

        mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
        mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle)); //Rotating!

        if (angle > 0f && angle < 100f || angle < 0f && angle > -90f)
        {

            //Reverse
            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x = 1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;

            //Limit
            angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, -24, 24);
            Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
            transform.rotation = target;

        }

        if (angle > 100f && angle < 180f || angle < -90f && angle > -180f)
        {

            //Reverse
            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x = -1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;

            //Limit
            angle = Mathf.Clamp(-angle, -24, 24);
            Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
            transform.rotation = target;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Mathf.Clamp(angle, 24, -24);` will work? _`Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max);`_

Comment: @J.vanLangen Yes, it works. I'm limiting two angles.

Comment: But does it handle when the min and max are reversed? Did you try to reverse it? `Mathf.Clamp(angle, -24, 24);`   It could cause the problem of 'snapping' the angle (not smooth)   image this.  `if(v < 24) v = 24; if (v > -24) v = -24;` get my point?

Comment: @J.vanLangen Hmm, 
It does not work smoothly and smoothly when reversed. Well; "if(v < 24) v = 24; if (v > -24) v = -24;"  how do I implement it? Thank you.

Comment: But then it will move reversed? You might try -angle `Mathf.Clamp(-angle, -24, 24);`

Comment: @J.vanLangen Thank you. But there is no smooth limit. It's the same in the video.

Comment: Update code. The problem continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement:

```
if (angle > 100f && angle < 180f || angle < -90f && angle > -180f)
```

The only angles which pass the statement are those which are either larger than 100 or smaller than -90. All of the numbers in the first range are larger than 25, and all the numbers in the second range are lower than -25.... so the value will always become either 25 or -25.

Inside the second statement, try adding or subtracting something from the angle until you get a value within your desired range. Maybe something like this:

```
if (angle > 100) angle -= 100;
if (angle < -90) angle += 90;
```